# Mongodb aggregate lookup group large data slow

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Hello I am new in Mongodb and having a problem with aggregate lookup query.

```
dbstock.aggregate([
{ 
    $match: {
        "stockLocation": "stockId",
        "companyId": "companyId"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "items",
        let: { item: "$stockItemCode", company: "$companyId" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match:
                { $expr:
                    { $and:
                        [
                            { $eq: [ "$itemCode",  "$$item" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$companyId", "$$company" ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 0, itemName: 1, companyId: 1 } }
        ],
        as: "item"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$stockItemCode",
        itemName: { $last: "$itemName" },
        companyId: { $last: "$companyId" },
        stockLocation: { $last: "$stockLocation" },
        positiveQuantity: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $gt: ['$quantity', 0] }, "$quantity", 0] } },
        negativeQuantity: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $lt: ['$quantity', 0] }, "$quantity", 0] } },
        item: { $last: "$item" }
    }
},
], {
   allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Query working Good without $group but when I use $group in my query it's very slow sometimes it's takes 5 to 10 mins

Comment: Try to do this: Remove `$lookup` stage and perform the `$group` stage (removing/comenting `item` field). If it's slow, you have a huge set of data (nothing can be done). If it's fast / normal, you can shift `$lookup` stage at the end

Comment: When I remove $group stage or shift $group after $match stage it works perfect but with $group not working, also I remove all fields except _id but did'nt work.

Comment: Can you post please a sample data? You can share in this sandbox https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: I have use $lookup after $group now it's fast but "item" fields shows empty array.

Comment: Share please a sample data. Now your lookup should look like this: `let: { item: "$_id", company: "$companyId" },`